# decrement a column from a table while decrement a column from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables Aprovizionari (which means Supplies- of books) and Facturi (which means Invoices). The tables have the following structure:

```
create table Aprovizionari
(
  ID_Aprovizionare  int     identity(1,1) primary key, 
  CodCarte          char(3) foreign key references Carti(CodCarte),
  CodLibrarie       char(3) foreign key references Librarii(CodLibrarie),
  DataAprovizionare date    default getdate(), 
  Cantitate         int     default 1 
-- ^^^^^^^ it should decrement when Cantitate from Facturi increment
)

create table Facturi
( 
  CodFactura  char(3) primary key,
  CodClient   char(4) foreign key references Clienti(CodClient),
  CodCarte    char(3) foreign key references Carti(CodCarte),
  Cantitate   int     default 1,
-- ^^^^^^^ value from here must be decrement in Aprovizionari.Cantitate
  CodLibrarie char(3) foreign key references Librarii(CodLibrarie),
)
```

`Aprovizionari` (Supply) stores the  `Cantitate` (Quantity) of each book in stock.

Each record in `Facturi` (Invoices) stores a purchase of quantity `Cantitate` of a particular book.

Books can be identified by `CodCarte` in both tables.

Everytime an invoice is recorded in `Facturi`, the quantity of books invoiced should be subtracted from the quantity of the book available in `Aprovizionari`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I've tried to clarify your question, if you feel that I've altered the meaning at all you can click the `edited x minutes ago` link above and "rollback" to the previous version.

Comment: If you need help with that other question, post it as a new question and I'll have a look when I get some time but someone else will probably answer it first

Comment: I have posted it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't insert `Facturi` in too many different  places it should be quite easy to just perform the update on `Aprovizionari` after you do the `INSERT`, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO Facturi (CodCarte, Cantitate, ...)
VALUES (101, 2);

UPDATE Aprovizionari
SET Cantitate = Cantitate - 2
WHERE CodCarte = 101;
```

Otherwise you could do this with a trigger along the lines of:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Facturi_OnInsert
   ON Facturi
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE a 
    SET a.Cantitate = a.Cantitate - i.Cantitate
    FROM Aprovizionari a
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON i.CodCarte = a.CodCarte
END
```

Comment: The trigger works good! But there is another rule that I forgot to mention. The quantity of books invoiced should be subtracted from the quantity of the book available in Aprovizionari not only everytime an invoice is recorded in Facturi, but when CodLibrarie from Aprovizionari=CodLibrarie from Facturi too. So, I've just added   to the line  INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON i.CodCarte = a.CodCarte and a.CodLibrarie=i.CodLibrarie. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, I figured that might be the case but glad you solved it. If your problem is fully solved appreciate it if you accept the answer.

Comment: I accept the answer!. I have to do something to close the topic or some?

Comment: Haha you click the tick to the left of this answer to mark it as accepted which marks the question as answered - although it remains open to new answers forever. You can [find out more here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Just update Aprovizionari table's Cantitate column according to the quantities purchased i.e. From Facturi Table.

Or you can apply a trigger on Facturi table when any new invoice is generated i.e. any new entry in inserted into this table decrease quantity from Aprovizionari  table.